# Copy to clipboard does not work on several bulks of text

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a script I use where I click a button and a text is copied to the clipboard. However, this scrips does not seem to work when I have several buttons supposed to work on several pieces of text.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to work with two or more buttons/ texts?

```js
var copyBtn = document.querySelector('.js-copybtn');
if (copyBtn) {
    copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var copyText= document.querySelector('.js-copytext');
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(copyText);
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        } catch(err) {

        }
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="context">
<span class="js-copytext"><p>Text 1</p></span>
    <button class="btn btn-default js-copybtn CP"> Copy </button>
    </div>
    <div class="context">
    <span class="js-copytext"><p>Text 2</p></span>  
    <button class="btn btn-default js-copybtn CP"> Copy </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the buttons and attach the click event, then on the button, we just need to get the previous sibiling, which we can access with the property `previousElementSibling` after that the logic works fine.

```js
var copyBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.js-copybtn');
if (copyBtns && copyBtns.length) {
copyBtns.forEach((copyBtn) => {
    copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(copyBtn);
        var copyText= copyBtn.previousElementSibling;
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(copyText);
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        } catch(err) {

        }
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    });
});
}
```

```html
<div class="context">
<span class="js-copytext"><p>Text 1</p></span>
    <button class="btn btn-default js-copybtn CP"> Copy </button>
    </div>
    <div class="context">
    <span class="js-copytext"><p>Text 2</p></span>  
    <button class="btn btn-default js-copybtn CP"> Copy </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: That appears to have done the trick! Thanks for the correction.